# Matching one of N route filters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel is there a way to allow access to a route if at least one out of N filters is successful? For example:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@profile', 'before' => 'requireAdmin|requireIsMe'));
```

This filter will require both `requireAdmin` and `requireIsMe` to grant access to the route, but what I need is a way to denote that either `requireAdmin` **or** `requireIsMe` is sufficient to allow access. Is this possible, or will I have to create a new filter that combines them both (which is a terrible solution, since I'll have to do that for ALL filter combinations)?

The filters look a little something like:

```
Route::filter('requireAdmin', function () {
    if(Session::get('user')->GetRole() != Role.Admin)
        return Redirect::to('/');
});

Route::filter('requireIsMe', function($id) {
    if(Session::get('user')->GetId() != $id)
        return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

What I need is: given those two filters, is there a way to tell a route that **only one** of them needs to pass in order to allow the request to continue as normal (in this example, both Admins and users with a matching ID should be able to proceed to `/user/{id}`). Is this possible? Or is there a smarter way to handle this kind of filtering?

Comment: What are in your filters? If I remember right, they only "cancel" a request if they redirect or return a response of some kind. If they return nothing, then they should follow to the next filter, and finally route to the controller/method. In that way, it can be an "OR" rather than "AND". I think - I'm curious about what your logic is in the filters to determine if my assumption is correct.

Comment: Just added filter descriptions in the question. The `requireIsMe` filter is empty now, as I haven't gotten around to writing it. So a solution to the problem would allow access to a route with `requireIsMe|requireAdmin` using an account that wasn't an admin (since `requireIsMe` is always a 'success'). If there's a way to get similar functionality from route filters without using returns, that might be a path to solving the problem...

Comment: So I'm trying to understand - You have your `requireAdmin` filter setup, which is great. If you then setup `requireIsMe` similarly to NOT return anything if the request passes find (if the user "is me" or whatever your requirements are), why would that not work for your app logic? Another way to ask the question: Under what condition would that **not** behave as desired?

Comment: Conditions that result in undesired behavior: It fails when Sue (the logged in user) is **not** an Admin (`requireAdmin` fails) but Sue **is** the user being requested (`requireIsMe` succeeds). Alternately, once `requireIsMe` is implemented, it will fail when Bob (another logged in user) **is** an Admin (`requireAdmin` succeeds), but is **not** the user being requested (`requireIsMe` fails).

Comment: The question is can route filters work as a logical OR instead of a logical AND (which is what `requireAdmin|requireIsMe` is, an AND)

Comment: When Sue isn't an admin, why doesn't the redirect take place? Does that filter get skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complex approach.
So you'll have to declare a new function in global.php:

```
function getFilters($filters)
{
    $exploded = explode('|', $filters);
    foreach($exploded as $filter)
    {
            $filterClass = ucwords($filter).'Filter';
            $return = with(new $filterClass)->filter();
            if( $return === null ) return strtolower($filter);
    }

    return strtolower($filters);
}
```

Now the next thing is to use "classes" for your filters. This is filters.php:

```
Route::filter('test', 'TestFilter');
Route::filter('test2', 'Test2Filter');

class TestFilter {
    public function filter() {
        if( 1 == 1 ) return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
class Test2Filter {
    public function filter() {
        if( 1 == 2 ) return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

And finally, you'll have to call "getFilters()" on the route and pass to it the filters you want (instead of before=> 'test|test2'):

```
Route::get('test', array('before' => getFilters('test|test2'), function(){
    dd('Hello');
}));
```

#### Now the explanation:

The aim of the `getFilters()` function is to test filters before they get called on the route, if one of them doesn't return something this will make the function return just the filter who succeeded to before(). In the example above, test2 will fail, but test will succeed, so the function will just return test as a filter to the route. Now, if the 2 filters fail, the function will return the filters string so that Laravel will take care of the response.

**Note:** It's prefereable to pass CamelCaseLongName as filter string so that `getFilters()` calls the corresponding class correctly. The returned string to `before` will always be lowercase.

You can then customize `getFilters()` so that it parses strings to get what's after the colons as parameters, just like you'd do it with normal filters (ex: test|test2:param1,param2')

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I ended up writing something similar, but I think this is a little more straightforward :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not really know but you could create a filter which calls this two and returns true if one of them do ;)

Comment: Only problem with that is then I have to do it for every iteration of filter that I want to combine. `requireAdminOrIsMe`, `requireUserOrIsMe`, `requireGuestOrIsMe`, etc. It'll work, but I'm trying to avoid making N! filters :)